# Postmessage not being sent until window receives focus. C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, sendmessage, postmessage

I'm trying to Postmessage send key inputs to an application. The issue is that the message is being sent only when the application becomes active or gains focus.

Here is my goal:
I need the application to receive inputs either while it is not focused, or via some pseudo-focus called via postmessage before the input is sent (I have tried:  `NativeMethods.PostMessage(mainHwnd, 0x0007, 0, 0);`  "0x0007" is WM_SETFOCUS but this doesn't do anything). Any assistance would be very helpful, I've been at this for more hours than I care to count.

Here is all of the relevant code I'm using:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

internal static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 uMsg, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam);
}

class Test
{
    const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    const int WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;
    //const int WM_SETFOCUS = 0x0007;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    public static void SendKey()
    {
        IntPtr mainHwnd = NativeMethods.FindWindow(null, "Test Application");
        NativeMethods.PostMessage(mainHwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, (int)Keys.A, 0);
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        NativeMethods.PostMessage(mainHwnd, WM_KEYUP, (int)Keys.A, 0);
    }
}

class TryTheThing{
    public void Send() {
        Test.SendKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a means to send keys to an inactive window/application with UI Automation? Specifically keystrokes with key up and key down states. I'm trying to send inputs to a non native window application. A reference to this functionality would be helpful.

Comment: I understand but for my purposes I need to control when up and down states are sent. I need to hard code key states to emulate holding keys. I also do not see any examples online of this functionality. An example would be helpful.

Comment: "Microsoft UI Automation is an accessibility framework for Windows. It provides programmatic access to most UI elements on the desktop." - [docs.microsoft.com](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-uiautomationoverview)

As stated, I looked into the API. There are no references about sending keys to applications in general, especially to an application that has no traditional controls (combobox, buttons) Let me reiterate: **This is not a native windows application or web application**. Even so, Windows automation cannot send keys. I hope this clears up any confusion.

Comment: **You were able to send text to Notepad with UIA because it is a windows native application OR had a traditional control**, in this case an **Edit Control**. I have stated many times that this application is not a user interface and has no such controls. On top of this I have stated that I do not wish to just simply **'send text'.** I wish to specify up/down states with the characters that I send. UIA does not have this functionality. Your attitude of simply not _"having to worry about the nitty gritty"_ is not helpful. Also your downvote is unwarranted, I clearly state the steps I have taken.

Comment: The only time a WPF app ( BTW WPF applications do have controls, please read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8 ) or DirectX application would allow the use of UIA is if the application was programmed to allow the usage of UIA. The need to hardcode the functionality in the program, it does not simple just work in those examples.

Answer (score 1):

Windows does not allow you to send keystrokes to non-focused applications. Your only option is to force the window to be focused first. This can be achieved by P/Invoking [`SetForegroundWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

```
NativeMethods.SetForegroundWindow(mainHwnd);
```

Comment: As a side note, I've built a library called InputHelper which wraps common input simulation methods like SendInput and posting of window messages. If you're interested: https://github.com/Visual-Vincent/InputHelper

Comment: I do appreciate the help and your library does look useful. However, I really need to find a way to use this while the window is inactive. I've made this work like you describe but by minimizing user interaction, I eliminate human error. I have combed through the internet trying to find solutions to getting this to work with an inactive window. Even if it is not windows, I would like to find it... i.e. I'm looking into SharpDX for DirectInput but it looks like it only detects inputs not sends them. I'm upping your answer because you actually tried to provide some help, for that I'm grateful.

Comment: @Zoetyc Sorry for my late reply. Simulating input to an unfocused app is not easy to accomplish, if at all possible. I might be wrong, but if I recall correctly there are limitations/restrictions when it comes to posting input-related window messages to non-focused applications. Are you looking to automate a any app or a single, specific one? If the latter, do you know what type of an app it is? (e.g. Win32, UWP, WPF, DirectX, etc.)

Comment: Certain apps may also listen to input in other ways than the standard window messages, such as through raw input window messages (see: [Raw Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/raw-input)) or DirectInput (as you discovered). In this case the app itself may have implemented its own procedure for discarding input when it does not have focus, which is outside of Windows's control and therefore not something the standard APIs can do anything about.

Comment: Thank you for responding! I did find a solution using an Autohotkey wrapper. For some reason using an AutoIt wrapper would not work even though they share very similar commands. Essentially I created a function which monitors up and down key states internally and per each key press I send a focus command. The big difference is I'm focusing a process ID, as opposed to a control (which this program does not have). I honestly cannot believe this works and it was the only possible solution I could get to work outside of sending DX inputs or trying to emulate inputs directly in memory.